# Which statistical method should I use to compare test results of two groups with each other and with exact values?

Tags: repeated-measures, measurement-error, measurement, agreement-statistics

I am currently working on an in-vitro medical device for an academy project with my teammates to see if our approach to a certain problem is working. We are hiring two groups of volunteers (15 people each, one group for control, one has the condition the device detects) of whom body liquid samples will be used for device performance tests under real conditions. The samples taken will also be measured by using known methods. So, in the end we will have four different datasets to be compared and evaluated to have some data like device error margin, random / systematic error or interference.

Which statistical approach would be best in this case, I wonder?